# How do you organise a large html file?

Tags: html, jsp

I have already factored around 3500 lines of JS & CSS code out of a JSP file.

I am currently cleaning a large html file with greater than 1500 lines of code so that I can I can do some enhancement to the functionality.  How can I break this file up further to make it manageable and to make the structure of the web page visible in the jsp file?

Comment: First step: store every piece of scripted code ans stylesheets in separate files.

Comment: You have a static HTML file with 1500 lines of HTML code?

Comment: Why do you store JS and CSS code in a JSP file?

Comment: JS & CSS have *already* been moved out of JSP.  Now there is only static HTML in JSP which is 1500 lines long.

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan Why do you have 1500 lines of static HTML? That's a lot.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I have inherited the code and now I am trying to break it down

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan Could you provide some information about that HTML code?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Let me know what kind of information will be helpful and I will see how to provide it without violating company confidentiality.

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan Is it mainly textual data (like a novel)? Is it tabular data? Is the web-page a document (data), or an application (like Gmail or Facebook)? How long (in pixels) is the web-page?

Comment: The HTML file contains lot of <div>,<table>,<tr>, <td> for rendering grid / table, and different dialog overlays.  I haven't gone through the entire code but I suspect not all tags are used at the same time in the same page (But hidden and displayed under different scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

Use the "source code formatting" functionality of whatever IDE you are using. Almost all IDE's have this functionality. It will give you the structure as it indents the source code depending upon how nested the elements are. You mentioned you have 1500 lines of code. I'm guessing you have lot of styles which are are defined inline for each element. Create new classes in css file and assign them to elements to separate styling from the page structure. Launch the page in browser and use firebug or chromes developer tool to "chunk"  out the major structures like Navigation, Copyright information, Contact Notices, blah, blah. If you are using any backend technology like jsp, save the HTML for the common elements of your site as separate files. For example, your navigation section might be saved as navigation.html and include them in the required file for eg:

```
<?(some jsp tag to include that file here because I do not know jsp);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use my tags as controls and templates, for example:

**masterPage.tag** file - general site template

```
<%@ tag description="page template" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>    
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>${title} | ${app.servName}</title>

        <link href="${app.staticUrl}/css/general.css${v}"     rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>  
        <jsp:doBody />
    </body>
</html>
```

**comments.jsp** - page with comments list(used masterPage.tag as template and commentsList.tag as controls)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="utd" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/templates/default" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="uc" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/controls/" %>

<utd:masterPage>
    <div class="post-comments">
        <uc:commentsList comments="${post.comments}" />
    </div>
</utd:masterPage>
```

`<jsp:doBody>` will be replaced in master page with content in `<utd:masterPage>`

**commentsList.tag** - control, rendering comments, used in several places

```
<%@ tag description="render comments" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ attribute name="comments" required="true" type="java.util.List" description="comments list" %>

<c:if test="${not empty comments}">
    <ul class="comments">
        <c:forEach items="${comments}" var="comment" varStatus="i">
            <li>
                <div class="comments-text">
                    ${comment.friendlyCreateDate} 
                    <p>
                        ${comment.text}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</c:if>
```

- i try logic html block make in control, this control may be used in other page
- controls may in itself have other controls